# how to pad 3d numpy array if it's smaller than specified size

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am working on CT scan images and I want to extract a small patch from cancer location of scans for example (16,40,40)(z,y,x), sometimes the location are on the corners and cannot get the size that decided before, for solving that problem tried to do padding in all side, here is my code:

```
M,N,P=(16,40,40)
temp_img = np.ndarray([16,40,40],dtype=np.float32)

                center = np.array([node_z, node_y, node_x])   # nodule center
                v_center = np.rint((center-origin)/spacing)  # nodule center in voxel space (still x,y,z ordering)

                temp_imgtemp_img[:,:,:] = img_array[int(v_center[0]-(M/2)):int(v_center[0]+(M/2)),\
                                   int(v_center[1]-(N/2)):int(v_center[1]+(N/2)),\
                                   int(v_center[2]-(P/2)):int(v_center[2]+(P/2))]
                m,n,p=temp_img.shape
                a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2=0,0,0,0,0,0

                if (m,n,p) != (M,N,P):
                    if m != M:
                        a=M-m
                        a1=a/2
                        a2=a-a1

                    if n != N:
                        b=N-n
                        b1=b/2
                        b2=b-b1

                    if p != P:
                        c=P-p
                        c1=c/2
                        c2=c-c1   

                transform=((a1,a2),(b1,b2),(c1,c2))
                temp_img = np.pad(temp_img,transform,'linear_ramp')

                plt.imshow(temp_img[5], cmap='gray')
                plt.title('image')
                plt.grid(which='major', linewidth='0.8', color='red')
                plt.show()
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: `pad_width` must be of integral type.
```

by changing `a1=a/2` to `a1=a//2` as suggested in one of the answers below the above problem is solved but I get the new error:

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (20,50,50) into shape (25,50,50)
```

which means that my real problem is not solved, cuz when tried this solution the value is rounded and the shape gets smaller or begger than specified shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stems from here:

```
a1=a/2
```

If a is odd, a1 will be a floating point number.  So you should do a truncating divide like `a//2` or round and cast back to int like `int(round(a/2))`.

Comment: @Jhon Zwinck, great answer the problem has been solved, but I get a new error, see the link below, its error message: https://ibb.co/hOgABp

Comment: @honar.cs: Please take your time to try to fix that one, I don't know offhand what's wrong, but if you get stuck just post a new question with the new problem.

Comment: sorry, but the problem not solved, I did an error in the code, that why I saw it as solved. when rounding the division the size is getting to smaller or begger than specified size.